# Moving to nextField after getting max length and to the previous one after getting 0 length

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Hi :) So first of all maybe the code..

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let newString = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) else { return true }
    var newLength = newString.characters.count

    switch textField {
    case numberTextField:
        textField.text = newString.grouping(every: 4, with: " ")

        if newLength > 18 {
            dateTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

    case dateTextField:
        textField.text = newString.grouping(every: 2, with: "/")

        if newLength > 4 {
            cvcTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if (textField.text?.isEmpty)! {
            numberTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

    case cvcTextField:
        textField.text = newString

        if newLength >= 3 {
            newLength = 3
        } else if (textField.text?.isEmpty)! {
            dateTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

    default:
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

I have 3 `UITextFields`. The first one is putting space every 4 characters, second slash every 2, but it doesn't matter. We want to move smoothly between them.

So moving to next `UITextField` after getting above `MaxLength` is pretty simple. It just sets newResponder to the next `UITextField`. Cool.. But what if we are in the middle `UITextField` it's empty and we want to move to the previous one ? Pressing delete Button on keyboard does nothing (should we detect backspace?). After inputing for example one number, erasing it, it works... it goes to the previous so everything works quite good, besides empty `UITextField`..

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** So I think what could solve the problem is after pressing new number on the current `TextField` that is above maxLenght should go straight to the next TextField, and instead of having empty `UITextField` it should be filled with the number that we pressed on previous `UITexField` is it possible ?

Comment: You want if you are in textfied 2 (which is empty) and you press back space then you want to make textfield 1 first responder ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I meant delete Button, sorry ;)